# Solving limit of $\frac{1}{x+1}(e^{2\pi i(x+1)}-1)$ as $x\rightarrow -1$ without l'Hopital

Tags: limits, complex-numbers, limits-without-lhopital

I have no idea how to solve the limit of

$$\frac{1}{x+1}(e^{2\pi i(x+1)}-1)$$ as $x\rightarrow -1$, without using l'Hopital's rule.

I don't even know where to start at all. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This limit is *by definition* the derivative of the function $$f:x\mapsto e^{2\pi i(x+1)}$$ at $$x=-1$$ which can also (and more simply) be computed as the derivative of the function $$g:t\mapsto e^{2\pi it}$$ at $$t=0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\exp(2\pi i(x+1))-1 = \cos(2\pi(x+1))-1+i\sin(2\pi(x+1))$.

Can you say anything about $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\cos t-1}{t}$ and $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\sin t}{t}$?

Comment: Well, the first limit is $0$ and the second is $1$, so that gives me $0 + 1i$, no? I feel like an idiot, but then, where does the $2\pi$ come from? (Because the answer is $2\pi i$.)

Comment: Almost! What you need is a small correction: $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\sin 2\pi t}{t} = 2\pi\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\sin 2\pi t}{2\pi t} = 2\pi$.

Comment: Yes, I get it, woho! Thank you!

Comment: But how do you solve the cos and sin limits without L'Hopital? Taylor series?

Comment: Well, mostly depends on how you define the functions. From geometry you easily derive (for the sine case) that $\sin x<x+(1-\cos x)$ and $\sin x+(1-\cos x)>x$, which together with $\lim_{t\to0}\cos x=1$ gives $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$. For the cosine, some similar tricks probably work.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \lim_{x\to -1} \frac{e^{2\pi i(x+1)}-e^{2\pi i(-1+1)}}{x-(-1)} $$
is *by definition* the derivative of $e^{2\pi i(x+1)}$ at $x=-1$.

Differentiate that symbolically (chain rule!), plug in $-1$, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use taylor expansion of $\exp(u)=1+u+u^2/2+O(u^3)$, in which you replace $u=2\pi i(x+1)$.

Remember that you have to change the limit.